# how to automatically copy the files in android specific folder (serve via ftp server) to local hard disk?

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, ftp

My situation is like this :
In Android Phone, I have CX_FileExplorer app installed.

From within that app, there is an option "Access From PC". So....

1. I turn on the wifi hotspot on the phone
2. Connect my PC to that phone's hotspot
3. in CX_FileExplorer I tap "Start Service" button
4. CX_FileExplorer give : ftp://xxx.xxx.xx.x:xxxx number
5. and it say : enter the above address in file explorer on PC
6. So, I type that address in PC file explorer
7. Then I can browse all my phone's folders within the PC explorer
8. I can copy any file from the phone's folder A then paste it to the PC folder B.

My question:
How to have Windows 10 in my PC to auto detect that if there are files in phone's folder A which are not in the PC folder B then copy those files from phone's folder A to PC folder B ?

Any kind of help would be appreciated.
Thank you in advanced.

PS :
Before, I've done something like that by creating Windows 10 hostednetwork and make a shared folder in PC. Then from Android phone, I use SMBSync app where each one minute will copy the newly created file (if any) in the phone's folder A to the PC shared folder B. But to make a wifi connection from the phone to that PC "hotspot" hostednetwork is temperamental. Sometimes it can connect, sometimes it can't (mostly can't), where in the wifi phone interface I get "*Obtaining IP Address....*" forever. Even now it's been two days for almost 48 hours, I can't make it to connect to that PC "hotspot" hostednetwork. That's why now I'm looking for another way.

Comment: So effectively you are searching for a two-way FTP file/folder synchronization program for Windows.

Comment: [SyncThing](https://syncthing.net/)

Comment: @Robert, yes something like that. Thank you.

Comment: @JW0914, thank you for the link. I will go there right now.